# Can I point a CNAME to a subpage on Google Sites?

Tags: dns, subdomain, cname, google-sites

Simple question:
I followed the instructions and now I have a CNAME pointing `www.mydomain.com` to my Google Sites site.

I want to add another, pointing `mike.mydomain.com` to `https://sites.google.com/site/subpages/mike`, `dave.mydomain.com` to ...`/dave` etc.

Is this possible? If so, where do I configure it in Google Sites?

Comment: using site forwarding is not applicable here, since I'd like to have several subdomains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is posible, this is the official google help about this topic:

[Can I point a CNAME to a subpage on Google Sites?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20686/can-i-point-a-cname-to-a-subpage-on-google-sites)

I quote:

> Sites outside of Google Apps
>
> If you own a domain and have access to change the CNAME record, you can map any site created in Google Sites outside of Google Apps (for example, sites.google.com/site) to a custom URL:
>
> 1. Select Manage Site from the More Actions drop-down menu.
> 2. Click the Web Address tab.
> 3. Enter your custom URL in the Web Address text box, then click the Add button at the top of the page.
>
> **Changing your CNAME record**
>
> Depending on your domain registrar, you may need to make changes to your CNAME record in order for your site to be mapped:
>
> 1. Sign in to the site where you control your own site with custom URL.
> 2. Navigate to your Domain Name Server (DNS) management page. The location and name of this page varies by host, but can generally be found in the Domain Management or Advanced Settings section.
> 3. Find the CNAME settings and in the section 'CNAME value or alias,' enter the sub-domain you'd like to map the URL to. The sub-domain for www.example.com would be www.
> 4. Set the CNAME destination to the following address: ghs.googlehosted.com
> 5. Save your changes with your domain host.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible using CNAME.

You may want to use a URL FRAME method if your registrar panel permit it.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on URL FRAME?

Comment: I'm using Namecheap [link](http://www.namecheap.com?aff=16569) and from their help : You wish to redirect users to the actual location of your webpage but you need to have your domain name in the browser's address bar even after the redirection.

Comment: Oh, ok. That's called "site forwarding" on Godaddy, and as I've mentioned in the question, it's not applicable here, since I need more than one subdomain.

Comment: No, because URL forwarding exist also ! URL forwarding will redirect and the new URL visible in the address bar.

Comment: http://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/313/77/what-is-url-frame-feature

Comment: Ok, this looks like a Namecheap unique feature. Also, it basically seems like it's showing the subpage you want in a frame on Namecheap's site - not really my desired behavior.

Comment: Sorry but you got it wrong. This is not glued with namecheap at all. The URL could be anything. Other registrars are offering the same feature.